# How to give some different value to column in drilldown depending on its value

Tags: highcharts

I have used column with drilldown highchart.
here after clicking on a particular column I am getting this

[image]

this works completely fine. what I want is to give those columns having value exactly 8.00 some different color(say green).How can it be possible?

```
    series: [{
                        name: 'Attendance',
                        colorByPoint: true,
                        data: [{
                            name: 'Jan',
                            y: Attendances.data.YearlyReport[0],
                            drilldown: 'Jan',
                        }, {
                            name: 'Feb',
                            y: Attendances.data.YearlyReport[1],
                            drilldown: 'Feb'
                        }, {
                            name: 'March',
                            y: Attendances.data.YearlyReport[2],
                            drilldown: 'March'
                        }, {
                            name: 'April',
                            y: Attendances.data.YearlyReport[3],
                            drilldown: 'April'
                        }, {
                            name: 'May',
                            y: Attendances.data.YearlyReport[4],
                            drilldown: 'May'
                        }, {
                            name: 'June',
                            y: Attendances.data.YearlyReport[5],
                            drilldown: 'June'
                        }, {
                            name: 'July',
                            y: Attendances.data.YearlyReport[6],
                            drilldown: 'July'
                        }, {
                            name: 'Aug',
                            y: Attendances.data.YearlyReport[7],
                            drilldown: 'Aug'
                        }, {
                            name: 'Sep',
                            y: Attendances.data.YearlyReport[8],
                            drilldown: 'Sep'
                        }, {
                            name: 'Oct',
                            y: Attendances.data.YearlyReport[9],
                            drilldown: 'Oct'
                        }, {
                            name: 'Nov',
                            y: Attendances.data.YearlyReport[10],
                            drilldown: 'Nov'
                        }, {
                            name: 'Dec',
                            y: Attendances.data.YearlyReport[11],
                            drilldown: 'Dec'
                        }]
                    }],  
  drilldown: {
                        series: 
                            [{
                            name: 'Jan',
                            id: 'Jan',
                            data: [
                                [
                                    '1',
                                    parseFloat(Attendances.data.MonthlyReport[1 * 33 + 1])

                                ],
                                [
                                    '2',
                                      parseFloat(Attendances.data.MonthlyReport[1 * 33 + 2])
                                ],
                                [
                                    '3',
                                      parseFloat(Attendances.data.MonthlyReport[1 * 33 + 3])
                                ],
                                [
                                    '4',
                                      parseFloat(Attendances.data.MonthlyReport[1 * 33 + 4])
                                ],
                                [
                                    '5',
                                    parseFloat(Attendances.data.MonthlyReport[1 * 33 + 5]),


                                ],
                                [
                                    '6',
                                      parseFloat(Attendances.data.MonthlyReport[1 * 33 + 6])
                                ],
                                [
                                    '7',
                                      parseFloat(Attendances.data.MonthlyReport[1 * 33 + 7])
                                ],
                                [
                                    '8',
                                   parseFloat(Attendances.data.MonthlyReport[1 * 33 + 8])
                                ],
                                [
                                    '9',
                                     parseFloat(Attendances.data.MonthlyReport[1 * 33 + 9])
                                ],
                                [
                                    '10',
                                     parseFloat(Attendances.data.MonthlyReport[1 * 33 + 10])
                                ],
                                [
                                    '11',
                                      parseFloat(Attendances.data.MonthlyReport[1 * 33 + 11])
                                ],
                                [
                                    '12',
                                     parseFloat(Attendances.data.MonthlyReport[1 * 33 + 12])
                                ],
                                [
                                    '13',
                                      parseFloat(Attendances.data.MonthlyReport[1 * 33 + 13])
                                ],
                                [
                                    '14',
                                     parseFloat(Attendances.data.MonthlyReport[1 * 33 + 14])
                                ],
                                [
                                    '15',
                                      parseFloat(Attendances.data.MonthlyReport[1 * 33 + 15])
                                ],
                                [
                                    '16',
                                    parseFloat(Attendances.data.MonthlyReport[1 * 33 + 16])
                                ],
                                [
                                    '17',
                                     parseFloat(Attendances.data.MonthlyReport[1 * 33 + 17])
                                ],
                                [
                                    '18',
                                     parseFloat(Attendances.data.MonthlyReport[1 * 33 + 18])
                                ],
                                [
                                    '19',
                                     parseFloat(Attendances.data.MonthlyReport[1 * 33 + 19])
                                ],
                                [
                                    '20',
                                     parseFloat(Attendances.data.MonthlyReport[1 * 33 + 20])
                                ],
                                [
                                    '21',
                                     parseFloat(Attendances.data.MonthlyReport[1 * 33 + 21])
                                ],
                                [
                                    '22',
                                      parseFloat(Attendances.data.MonthlyReport[1 * 33 + 22])
                                ],
                                [
                                    '23',
                                     parseFloat(Attendances.data.MonthlyReport[1 * 33 + 23])
                                ],
                                [
                                    '24',
                                     parseFloat(Attendances.data.MonthlyReport[1 * 33 + 24])
                                ],
                                [
                                    '25',
                                      parseFloat(Attendances.data.MonthlyReport[1 * 33 + 25])
                                ],
                                [
                                    '26',
                                     parseFloat(Attendances.data.MonthlyReport[1 * 33 + 26])
                                ],
                                [
                                    '27',
                                    parseFloat(Attendances.data.MonthlyReport[1 * 33 + 27])
                                ],
                                [
                                    '28',
                                    parseFloat(Attendances.data.MonthlyReport[1 * 33 + 28])
                                ],
                                [
                                    '29',
                                     parseFloat(Attendances.data.MonthlyReport[1 * 33 + 29])
                                ],
                                 [
                                    '30',
                                    parseFloat(Attendances.data.MonthlyReport[1 * 33 + 30])
                                 ],
                                 [
                                    '31',
                                     parseFloat(Attendances.data.MonthlyReport[1 * 33 + 31])
                                 ]
                            ]}, 
                            {
                            name: 'Feb',
                            id: 'Feb',
                            data: [
                                   ....
```

Answer (score -1):

[check fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/umtfkyo2/)

html

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

js

```
$(function () {
// Create the chart
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares. January, 2015 to May, 2015'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Click the columns to view versions. Source: <a href="http://netmarketshare.com">netmarketshare.com</a>.'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Total percent market share'
        }

    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
            }
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',

        data: [{
            name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            y: 56.33,
            drilldown: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'
        }, {
            name: 'Chrome',
            y: 24.03,

            drilldown: 'Chrome'
        }, {
            name: 'Firefox',
            y: 8.00,
            drilldown: 'Firefox'
        }, {
            name: 'Safari',
            y: 4.77,
            drilldown: 'Safari'
        }, {
            name: 'Opera',
            y: 0.91,
            drilldown: 'Opera'
        }, {
            name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
            y: 0.2,
            drilldown: null
        }]
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
            name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            id: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            data: [
                [
                    'v11.0',
                    24.13
                ],
                [
                    'v8.0',
                    17.2
                ],
                [
                    'v9.0',
                    8.11
                ],
                [
                    'v10.0',
                    5.33
                ],
                [
                    'v6.0',
                    1.06
                ],
                [
                    'v7.0',
                    0.5
                ]
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Chrome',
            id: 'Chrome',
            data: [
                [
                    'v40.0',
                    5
                ],
                [
                    'v41.0',
                    4.32
                ],
                [
                    'v42.0',
                    3.68
                ],
                [
                    'v39.0',
                    2.96
                ],
                [
                    'v36.0',
                    2.53
                ],
                [
                    'v43.0',
                    1.45
                ],
                [
                    'v31.0',
                    1.24
                ],
                [
                    'v35.0',
                    0.85
                ],
                [
                    'v38.0',
                    0.6
                ],
                [
                    'v32.0',
                    0.55
                ],
                [
                    'v37.0',
                    0.38
                ],
                [
                    'v33.0',
                    0.19
                ],
                [
                    'v34.0',
                    0.14
                ],
                [
                    'v30.0',
                    0.14
                ]
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Firefox',
            id: 'Firefox',
            data: [
                [
                    'v35',
                    2.76
                ],
                [
                    'v36',
                    2.32
                ],
                [
                    'v37',
                    2.31
                ],
                [
                    'v34',
                    1.27
                ],
                [
                    'v38',
                    1.02
                ],
                [
                    'v31',
                    0.33
                ],
                [
                    'v33',
                    0.22
                ],
                [
                    'v32',
                    0.15
                ]
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Safari',
            id: 'Safari',
            data: [
                [
                    'v8.0',
                    2.56
                ],
                [
                    'v7.1',
                    0.77
                ],
                [
                    'v5.1',
                    0.42
                ],
                [
                    'v5.0',
                    0.3
                ],
                [
                    'v6.1',
                    0.29
                ],
                [
                    'v7.0',
                    0.26
                ],
                [
                    'v6.2',
                    0.17
                ]
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Opera',
            id: 'Opera',
            data: [
                [
                    'v12.x',
                    0.34
                ],
                [
                    'v28',
                    0.24
                ],
                [
                    'v27',
                    0.17
                ],
                [
                    'v29',
                    0.16
                ]
            ]
        }]
    }
},
function(chart){

        var max = 10;

        $.each(chart.series[0].data,function(i,data){

            if(data.y ==8.00)
                data.graphic.attr({
                    fill:'red'
                });

        });

    });
```

});

Comment: check link this may help full @akash

Comment: chart.series[0].data is for the initial data...I want to apply it for the drilldown data

Comment: this is for drildown chart.series[0] is pick first series

Comment: @Zubairsadiq This is not a proper way to change color of a column - it can be set in options or changed through [point.update](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.update). If you hover over your red column in your demo, then changed fill will be removed.